# Java 9 - how publisher and subscriber works

Tags: java-9, subscription, subscriber, publisher

I am trying to understand how `Subscriber` and `Publisher` works in **java 9**.

Here I have created one `subscriber` here and using `SubmissionPublisher` for publishing item .

I am trying to publish 100 strings to `subscriber`. If I do not make the `Client` program to `sleep` (**see commented code in `MyReactiveApp`**), I do not see all the items are published.

why is it not waiting for all the strings processed here:

```
strs.stream().forEach(i -> publisher.submit(i)); // what happens here?
```

If I replace the above code with, I see all the strings are printed in console

```
strs.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Client program that publishes using `SubmissionPublisher`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.SubmissionPublisher;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MyReactiveApp {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>();

        MySubscriber subs = new MySubscriber();
        publisher.subscribe(subs);


        List<String> strs = getStrs();

        System.out.println("Publishing Items to Subscriber");
        strs.stream().forEach(i -> publisher.submit(i));

        /*while (strs.size() != subs.getCounter()) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }*/

        //publisher.close();

        System.out.println("Exiting the app");

    }

    private static List<String> getStrs(){

        return Stream.generate(new Supplier<String>() {
            int i =1;
            @Override
            public String get() {
                return "name "+ (i++);
            }
        }).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Subscriber

```
import java.util.concurrent.Flow.Subscription;

public class MySubscriber implements java.util.concurrent.Flow.Subscriber<String>{

    private Subscription subscription;

    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        subscription.request(100);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String item) {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" item "+item);
        //subscription.request(1);
        counter++;

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+ " an error occured "+throwable);

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("activity completed");

    }
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

}
```

output:

```
Publishing Items to Subscriber
MySubscriber item name 1
MySubscriber item name 2
MySubscriber item name 3
MySubscriber item name 4
MySubscriber item name 5
Exiting the app
MySubscriber item name 6
MySubscriber item name 7
MySubscriber item name 8
MySubscriber item name 9
MySubscriber item name 10
MySubscriber item name 11
MySubscriber item name 12
```

Comment: Looks related to [Back-Pressure](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary#Back-Pressure) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>();
```

> Creates a new SubmissionPublisher using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() for async delivery to subscribers

see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html#SubmissionPublisher--

So actually

```
    strs.stream().forEach(i -> publisher.submit(i));
```

enqueues all submissions and delivers them asynchronously on another thread. But then the application is terminated. This is independent of the progress of the worker thread. This means that the application is terminated regardless of how many elements the worker thread has already delivered.

This can be different for each run. In the worst case, the application could be terminated before the first item is delivered.

**Threads**

If you want to verify that the main method of MyReactiveApp and the delivery in MySubscriber's onNext happen on different threads you can print out the names of the corresponding threads, e.g. in MyReactiveApp's main:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName())
```

will output `main` as thread name.

Whereas MySubscriber's onNext method will e.g. output something like `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1`.

**User and Deamon Threads**

Why does the application terminate although we still have a running thread?

There are two kind of threads in Java:

- user threads
- daemon threads

A Java program terminates when no longer any user threads are running, even when deamon threads are still running.

The main thread is a user thread. The SubmissionPublisher uses here worker threads from ForkJoinPool.commonPool(). These are daemon threads.

> All worker threads are initialized with Thread.isDaemon() set true.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, but can you please through some more light on **enqueues all submissions and delivers them asynchronously on another thread** .. are you referring to `publisher.submit`? As I was aware the created threads can be running after the main thread exits.

Comment: I've added infos about user and worker threads to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, You have provided details needed to me. accepting as answer.

Comment: After your answer, I have tried with fork join and found the similar behaviour. But I was wondering threads submitted to fork-join pool were not completed if the mail thread exits. see if you add details of it if you find them relevant here..

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Are you saying that you are creating your own thread factory by implementing the `newThread` method of ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory and delivering user threads? And why aren't these threads finished? Or is the question different?

Comment: Sorry - I missed about `ForkJoinPool` creates `daemon` threads while writing the comment.. Now it is clear to me. thanks